# Illustrator CC resets artboard preset from Desktop to Fire HD

Tags: adobe-illustrator, artboard, creative-cloud

I am building a wireframe in Adobe Illustrator CC and creating multiple artboards for different devices. My first two artboards have the presets of iPad Air and iPhone 5s respectively. I created a third artboard and tried to give it the default size of desktop 1280x800. I select that from the drop down menu, but Illustrator resets it to Fire HD. When I created the document and chose the first artboard, I chose "Device" (and iPad Air) instead of "Web" for "Profile". Could this be causing the problem? Is it possible to have both web and device artboard profiles in the same document?

Here I have selected the preset 1280x800:
[image]

Then when I click "OK", I notice that the artboard looks too small and that the preset up on the menu ribbon says Fire HD.
[image]

When I try to choose the desktop preset from the menu ribbon drop down, the setting doesn't keep.

[image]

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The Fire HD preset and the 1280 × 800 preset have identical settings.

It doesn't matter if you select print, web, devices, video and film, or basic rgb as the profile when first creating a document.

If the artboard is 1280 × 800px / pt, it will be described as 'Fire HD'.

As to the artboard 'looking too small', the iPhone 5s' screen resolution [1136 × 640px] is only marginally smaller than the Fire HD [1280 × 800]

TL;DR:

You aren't doing anything wrong. Illustrator is giving you some mixed signals.

Comment: Yep, you aren't doing anything wrong @Pixel, as dkovie pointed out, Illustrator just happens to have two presets that are named differently, but have identical settings. Even after it changes the name to `FireHD`, that is the only thing that has changed in the Artboard Options window.